# SugarCRM v6.5 How to get the field from another module and display it into a different module?

Tags: sugarcrm

I know about the relationship but they only get the primary field, not the other fields. For example, I have two modules, module 1 holds the personal information of the user while module 2 let us say holds the person's activities. in module 2 I would like to display the gender base on his information from module 1.

How can I proceed with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow below steps to achieve this:
Note: Make sure the Module-1 and Module-2 has one of the relationship 1-M or M-M

- Step-1: Create new field in Module-2 to store/display the gender
  values
- Step-2: Create new file in Module-2
  location(custom/modules/Module2/views/view.detail.php)

> ```
>  <?php
>     require_once('include/MVC/View/views/view.detail.php');
>     class Module2ViewDetail extends ViewDetail {
>
>         function Module2ViewDetail() {
>             parent::ViewDetail();
>         }
>
>       function display() {
>
>             $recordId = $this->bean->id;
>             global $db;
>               if($recordId){
>                   /* write a query to fetch gender($gender) from module */
>               }
>           $this->dv->process();
>
>           $this->ss->assign('GENDER',$gender);
>           echo $this->dv->display(); 
>         }
>
>     }
>
>  ?>
> ```

- Step 3: \custom\modules\Module2\metadata\detailviewdefs.php

Add the customCode in the gender field which you have created in Module2 like below. (Please note: Give the name of field similar to you custom field name):

```
 1 => 
     array (
     0 => 
       array (
          'name' => 'gender_c',
          'label' => 'LBL_GENDER',
          'customCode' => '{$GENDER}',
       ),
     1 => '',
),
```

Hope this will help you. Thanks!

Comment: I will suggest to write after save logic hook on Module1. And update the field gender  in module2.

Comment: how to do this implementation in SugarCRM v7.9?